# How can I reduce fluctuations in my validation accuracy?

Tags: neural-networks, python, cross-validation, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN with pictures data for binary classification and while my training accuracy increases, my validation accuracy keeps fluctuating between small and high values of accuracy. I have a small dataset, but I can't do anything to increase the number of samples. Is my model overfitting? Or maybe my model is too complicated?

This is my neural network:

```
# 1st Convolution Layer
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 2nd Convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5), padding='same'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 3rd Convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 4th Convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# Flattening
model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected layer 1st layer
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# Fully connected layer 2nd layer
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

[image]

Comment: You say you have a small dataset. How many samples are in it?

Comment: @civilstat 137 from one category and 136 from the other, split between training and validation.

Comment: I'm not an expert on neural networks, but my understanding is that CNNs aren't usually expected to work well (or even give stable performance estimates) unless there are thousands or tens of thousands of examples per class. If you are not training a CNN from scratch, only using your dataset to fine-tune a pre-built CNN, you *might* be able to get away with a smaller sample size, but this one still seems very small. Are you sure you really need CNNs for the substantive problem you are trying to solve with this model?

Comment: For example, maybe there is some other image processing you could do to extract features that are meaningful in the context of your data, and fit a much simpler predictive model using those features?

Comment: Agree with civilsat. Also, how big is your validation set? If it is small, then substantial fluctuations are to be expected.